# Why am I getting false alarm in this plot when all the values are 1 except at (5,5)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, interpolation, heatmap

Sorry, I cannot embed the image in my question due to my less than 10 reputation. So bear with me.

My test excel file hai 3 columns: x, y, z

```
x,y,z
0,0,1
0,1,1
0,2,1
0,3,1
0,4,1
0,5,1
0,6,1
0,7,1
0,8,1
0,9,1
1,0,1
1,1,1
1,2,1
1,3,1
1,4,1
1,5,1
1,6,1
1,7,1
1,8,1
1,9,1
2,0,1
2,1,1
2,2,1
2,3,1
2,4,1
2,5,1
2,6,1
2,7,1
2,8,1
2,9,1
3,0,1
3,1,1
3,2,1
3,3,1
3,4,1
3,5,1
3,6,1
3,7,1
3,8,1
3,9,1
4,0,1
4,1,1
4,2,1
4,3,1
4,4,1
4,5,1
4,6,1
4,7,1
4,8,1
4,9,1
5,0,1
5,1,1
5,2,1
5,3,1
5,4,1
5,5,9
5,6,1
5,7,1
5,8,1
5,9,1
6,0,1
```

The Cmap is 'jet'.
All the z values are 1 except at (5,5). So the result should be a map with red at (5,5) and blue everywhere else.
However this is not the case with map generated from the code below. It gives dark blue colored areas at points (0,6) and (6,0).

See the image here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mT32B.png)

Code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl

excel_data_df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx')
X= excel_data_df['x'].tolist()
Y= excel_data_df['y'].tolist()
Z= excel_data_df['z'].tolist()

x_list = np.array(X)
y_list = np.array(Y)
z_list = np.array(Z)

f = interp2d(x_list,y_list,z_list,kind="linear")

x_coords = np.arange(min(x_list),max(x_list)+1)
y_coords = np.arange(min(y_list),max(y_list)+1)
z = f(x_coords,y_coords)

fig = plt.imshow(z,
           extent=[min(x_list),max(x_list),min(y_list),max(y_list)],
           origin="lower", interpolation='bicubic', cmap= 'jet')

fig.axes.set_autoscale_on(False)
plt.scatter(x_list,y_list,400, facecolors='none')
plt.xlabel('X Values', fontsize = 15)
plt.ylabel('Y Values', fontsize = 15)
plt.title('Heatmap', fontsize = 20)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

In the Run terminal:
RuntimeWarning: No more knots can be added because the additional knot would
coincide with an old one. Probable cause: s too small or too large
a weight to an inaccurate data point. (fp>s)
kx,ky=1,1 nx,ny=11,11 m=100 fp=46.439909 s=0.000000
warnings.warn(RuntimeWarning(_iermess2[ierm][0] + _mess))

Comment: You should not post an image of text data, but the data. Nobody will bother to transcribe your data to text. Either post the text, or code that generates the text.

Comment: Maaz, you can generate X, Y, and Z with code:  X = []
Y = []
Z = []

[(X.append(i), Y.append(j), Z.append(9 if i == j == 5 else 1)) for i in range(10) for j in range(10)]

Comment: I want to make this code executable. it should only need an input of excel file. Can you suggest accordingly?